# Limit for HttpRuntime cache storage in mvc mini profiler

Tags: c#, mvc-mini-profiler, mvcminiprofiler

1. I believe that the mvc mini profiler stores all the response times in HttpRuntime cache. 
   Please let me know if I'm wrong but if that's the case then what is the max limit for this cache? How many operations can it profile before the cache is full? We are using the mini profiler for profiling operations of a test suite and the test suite will grow over time so I am concerned about this thing. Should I be concerned?
2. On a related note. When all the tests have been profiled I simply call the `Save` method in `SqlServerStorage` class of the mini profiler. And all the response times are saved to a SQL server database. Is there any way I could call the `Save` method more frequently without starting and stopping the profiler again and again? We just start it at the start of the test suite and end it when all the tests have been profiled. We consider one entry to the `MiniProfilers` table as one profiling session. Right now I am not able to call the 'Save' method more than once because it needs a new `MiniProfilerId` everytime it is called.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey Guys! Any inputs on the cache question? Thanks!

Comment: Can we answer this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not directly familiar with the mini profiler but I do have quite a bit of experience with the cache. The HttpRuntime.Cache property provides a reference to the System.Web.Caching.Cache class. Which is an implementation of the object cache. In general use this cache is static, so there is only one instance. You can configure the behavior of this Cache using the [Web.Config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178606%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) file. Some things to keep in mind about the windows cache, you will never get an out of memory error using it. The cache has a percentage of memory value that tells it how full it should get. Once it gets near that top memory usage percentage it will start to cull objects out of the cache starting with the oldest touched objects. So the short answer to your first question is no, don't worry about the memory limits, one of the main selling points of a managed language is that you should never have to worry about memory consumption, let the framework handle it.

As for #2 I wouldn't worry about it. The cache may throw away the response object itself but I would venture a guess that it's already been included in the result aggregation from the profilier, so you really shouldn't need the original request object itself unless you want to deep inspect it.

Long story short, I wouldn't worry about this anymore unless you hit an real issue. Let the cache do it's job and trust the engineers who built it knew what they were doing until you have proof otherwise.

Comment: Ya I think you're right. Let's hit a real issue first and then solve the problem at hand. Thanks for the reply.